Как реализовать сложный запрос к базе данных ROOM Android?
Простой запрос к базе данных ROOM Android может выглядеть например так
@Query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE name1 = :x AND name2 = :y")
fun getUser(x: String, y: String): List<User>

возможно ли написать запрос сложнее, по такому алгоритму?
WHERE (name1 = :x AND name2 = :y) OR (name1 = :y AND name2 = :x)

Скобки в запросе можно ставить?
И еще вопрос в догонку - в чем разница операторов сравнения = и LIKE
как здесь в примере

В догонку достаточно загуглить: https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-like/

Спасибо. Кажется и скобки работают в запросе. Удалять вопрос? )

Вы можете сами оформить ответ если считаете его полезным.
